# How to make connection to other computers in R?

Tags: r, csv, networking, connection, xls

I want to open file in another computer in the same network in R. How can I do that? I want to generate a csv file in that other computer but I got this "permission denied" error.

I know the hostname of the other computer along with filepath where I want to create my csv file. I know the userID and password of the other computer. I tried to read the help page about *connection* and *file.access* but I cannot find a function which I can type username and password to access the other computer.

I want to have something like this:

```
write.csv(x=data.frame(), file="\\\\hostname\\filepath\\filename", user='user', password='password')
```

Kindly let me know if this is even the correct way of doing it.

Thank you!

Comment: What transfer protocol you are using?

Comment: I am quite new with R so I am not sure what transfer protocol means. However I am in windows environment, using R server 3.3.2. Kindly let me know the example of a transfer protocol, so I can tell what it is for me.

Comment: FTP (file transfer protocol) or SFTP (secure FTP) could be the transfer protocol. But it can also be HTTP or SMB or ... . Did you tested the writing of a file to the remote host from shell (not from in R)? Eventually file= should be a connection (see the documentation of the function `write.csv`).

Comment: I have not tried to write a file from shell (or maybe Command Prompt). maybe I should try that one first. I can only open connection using Remote Desktop application or using Run command in Windows.

Comment: Have you tried interactively with `file.choose()`. If your remote machine is mounted with samba, you will be able to browse it and thus know the path with this function. Normally this can be something like `file="smb://hostname/filepath"`, but I am not sure of it with Windows...

Comment: What is R server? Are you using R locally or through a web browser?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Microsoft R Server is the R version from Microsoft to deal with big data. It is able to interact with Hadoop, Teradata, and closely integrated with SQL Server. It able to utilize Revolution Analytic packages.